# Simple, privacy-oriented, website metrics

Tags: google-analytics, website-metrics

I have a personal website (I work in academia) and I want to know how many people visited my website. Secondary, if possible, also for how long, and what pages they navigated to.

However, I don't want to know their location, language, screen size, ISP, etc. Moreover, I don't want Google or anyone else to get all this information from people visiting my website.

Is there any alternative to GA I can use? If possible, something barebone, self-hosted, and privacy oriented.

At the moment I use gohugo, netlify, and github to host my website and I have GA to monitor the traffic.

Comment: I personally use Matomo and I think it will satisfy your needs. It is 'self-hosted', 'privacy-oriented' and open source. https://matomo.org/

Comment: If you are still interested, check out [uxwizz.com](https://www.uxwizz.com) . There are multiple people using it in academia or healthcare, where you need all data to be self-hosted, but get more insights into what's happening on your websites/forms/applications or even to record the user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try open source analytics, but can or will be limited in support. Some of them that have considerable user base are  -

- [Snowplow Analytics](https://snowplowanalytics.com/products/snowplow-open-source/)
- [Piwik now Matamo](https://matomo.org/)
- [AWStats](http://www.awstats.org/) - more of a log analyzer tool

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't around at the time of your question, but I'd now suggest [Fathom](https://usefathom.com/). Fast, Simple and Privacy focussed.

Answer (score 0):

You should give **[GoatCounter](https://www.goatcounter.com)** a try:

> GoatCounter is an **open source web analytics platform available as a hosted service (free for non-commercial use) or self-hosted app**. It aims to offer easy to use and meaningful **privacy-friendly** web analytics as an alternative to Google Analytics or Matomo

This solution is **lightweight** (2.5Kb) and **privacy-aware**: it [does not use cookies or persistently storing any personal data](https://github.com/zgoat/goatcounter/blob/master/docs/sessions.markdown#goatcounters-solution)

You can learn more [in this presentation by the author](https://www.goatcounter.com/why) and checkout the screenshots [on the homepage](https://www.goatcounter.com/)

I'm using it since ~6 months with Hugo, works flawless. You just need to create a free account and insert a line of code in your footer to start using the hosted service, and then decide if you go for self-hosting

It's similar to Fathom, but the pricing is based on donations and can eventually be used for free